# Vulkan driver stops working when running in google remote desktop

Tags: drivers, remote-desktop, vulkan

I am running an ubuntu gcp instance with nvidia v100 attached. I installed the graphics drivers and checked the correctness using `nvidia-smi` and `vulkaninfo`. Both show no errors. This shows that the graphics drivers are installed correctly.

Now I want to have remote display access using [Google's remote desktop service](https://remotedesktop.google.com/). So I followed the [headless install instructions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine) and all seemd to go well until I tested the videocard. Somehow when running `vulkaninfo` in a terminal inside the remote desktop it errors with this message:

```
/build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:2700: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

I have googled everywhere and even searched the vulkaninfo sourcecode to understand where this error is originating from but I can't find it.

Does anyone know what causes this error? Why does the vulkan driver work fine in an ssh terminal but not in a virtual display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured out a way to get it to work but it is pretty hacky. I do not reccommand this for sensitive systems**

It all started with [this page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkAcquireXlibDisplayEXT.html) that tells us

> If the X11 server associated with dpy does not own display, or if permission to access it has already been acquired by another entity, the call must return the error code VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED.

This lead me to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74635/which-user-owns-x-display) and this command: `ps -ef | grep X`. This showed that the current display was started using `xvfb`. This is the [x virtual frame buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790838/vfb-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-virtual-framebuffer). Apparently [xvbf does not support vulkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631962/is-xvfb-with-mesa-19-2-compatible-with-vulkan). So let's see if we can make google-remote-desktop make use a normal x server (spoiler: yes!).

The code behind the `chrome-remote-desktop` service is in `/etc/init.d/chrome-remote-desktop`, which in turn runs `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop` ([sourcecode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/remoting/host/linux/linux_me2me_host.py)). In there we find that we can use the `CHROME_REMOTE_DESKTOP_USE_XORG` environment variable to make google-remote-desktop launch an Xorg display with the dummy driver. Let's enable it by adding the following line to the `/etc/environment` file:

```
CHROME_REMOTE_DESKTOP_USE_XORG=1
```

After restarting the service I got the following error

```
Only console users are allowed to run the X server
```

Why is X server not started by root? Because the chrome-remote-desktop service starts a separate display for each user in the name of that user.

To [fix above error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478742/error-when-trying-to-use-xorg-only-console-users-are-allowed-to-run-the-x-serve/529945#529945) you can edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and set `allowed_users = anybody`.

Now X server is complaining that the `-logfile` is only available when the server is run as root (i.e, with real-uid 0). If you are like me and don't care about logging you can edit `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop` and remove the following line (around line number 581):

```
"-logfile", "/dev/null",
```

Almost there!

Now X server is complaning that the `-config` must be a relative path. [This page](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) explains that the config file must be placed in `/etc/X11/<cmdline>` or `/usr/etc/X11/<cmdline>`. Looking through the sourcecode of `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop` we see the following:

```
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
        prefix="chrome_remote_desktop_",
        suffix=".conf", delete=False) as config_file:
      config_file.write(gen_xorg_config(self.sizes).encode())
```

At this moment the config file is created in `/tmp`, so let's move that. Add the following line between the prefix and suffix line:

```
dir="/etc/X11/",
```

X wants to receive a relative path so we have to change

```
"-config", config_file.name
```

to

```
"-config", os.path.basename(config_file.name)
```

And because we are not root we must give users write permission to this folder. So let's run:

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/X11
```

We are doing all this so that we can use the nvidia drivers. Replace the dummy driver:

```
      'Section "Device"\n'
      '  Identifier "Chrome Remote Desktop Videocard"\n'
      '  Driver "dummy"\n'
      '  VideoRam {video_ram}\n'
      'EndSection\n'
```

with the nvidia driver:

```
      'Section "Device"\n'
      '  Identifier "Chrome Remote Desktop Videocard"\n'
      '  Driver "nvidia"\n'
      '  VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"\n'
      '  VideoRam {video_ram}\n'
      'EndSection\n'
```

Somehow this setup does not like resizing, therefore I forced a single size by setting `DEFAULT_SIZES_XORG` to `"1920x1080"`.

And now it works!